# Append multiple files in subdirectories from a txt file

Tags: bash, debian

I have a file `/etc/test/custom.txt`, and I have a bunch of CFG files in sub-directories called `/etc/config/device1`, `/etc/config/device2`, `/etc/config/device3` these cfg filed are all in the subdirectories of `/etc/config/`

I need to append all of them with the contents of custom.txt.

I am really confused on how to do this and appreciate any advice anyone could offer.

When I update my application all my custom configs are wiped out so I want to create this bash script or w.e. to append all the config files with the contents of `custom.txt`

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to `cat` the file `custom.txt` then `tee` it to the `device` files.

```
$ cat /etc/test/custom.txt | tee -a /etc/config/{device1,device2,device3}
```

Comment: I have a ton of these device1.cfg device2.cfg files all in /etc/config subdirectories so I would need to search for device*.cfg in all subdirectories of /etc/config/ and append the contents of custom.txt to all matches